# Get GeoJSON properties

Tags: javascript, html, geojson

Here is a view of my GeoJSON:

```
var point_layer_WGS84_dist = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "x": 7.6789651, "y": 48.5066953, "distCoupe": 10000, "path": "coupes_10000_14995\\PM_10000.png" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 7.6789651, 48.5066953 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "x": 7.6788011, "y": 48.5063054, "distCoupe": 10045, "path": "coupes_10000_14995\\PM_10045.png" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 7.6788011, 48.5063054 ] } },
```

i want to get information from a geojson file, that i linked thought the HTML 
is there a possibilty like :

```
var feat = point_layer_WGS84_dist.getFeatureByPropertie("distCoupe",'10000')
var imageLocation = feat.path
```

leaflet is able to access to it, how can i do it too ?

Comment: Just access it like a normal JS object. Use either the dot notation or square bracket notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `getFeaturesByProperty` by using `Array.prototype.filter`:

```js
var point_layer_WGS84_dist = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},

  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {"x": 7.6789651, "y": 48.5066953, "distCoupe": 10000, "path": "coupes_10000_14995\\PM_10000.png"},
      "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [7.6789651, 48.5066953]}
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {"x": 7.6788011, "y": 48.5063054, "distCoupe": 10045, "path": "coupes_10000_14995\\PM_10045.png"},
      "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [7.6788011, 48.5063054]}
    }]
};

point_layer_WGS84_dist.getFeaturesByProperty = function(key, value) {
  return this.features.filter(function(feature){
    if (feature.properties[key] === value) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
};

var feats = point_layer_WGS84_dist.getFeaturesByProperty('distCoupe', 10000);

console.log(feats);
```

Comment: and how can i use it if my GeoJSON variable is in an other file that i linked thanks to the HTML ?

Comment: @NanBlanc Do you mean the `point_layer_WGS84_dist` object is from another .js file? If yes, you can import that .js file first, assign the data to a global variable (such as `point_layer_WGS84_dist`), and then import the above code snippet (remove the `point_layer_WGS84_dist` initialization part, of course).

Comment: Never mind, i got it :) i just had to call point_layer_WGS84_dist.js before my index.js. // an other question : how can i extract particular properties of the object feat, now i extracted it ? i tried  feats.properties.distCoupe, but got an error "Cannot read property 'distCoupe' of undefined"

Comment: i found the answer alone : 
console.log(feats[0].properties.z); Thanks again for your awesome help !!!